# Cannot use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as Controller because the name is already in use

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have been learning to use Laravel, watching Larcasts and using the Docs, I came across a lesson where Eloquent is being described but I'm stuck with the error:

```
at HandleExceptions->fatalExceptionFromError(
  array(
    'type' => '64',
    'message' => 'Cannot use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as Controller because the name is already in use'
  )
)
```

I'm very confused and have now copied the examples provided exactly but I still get the error. I am using Laravel 5, so I don't know if there has been some undocumented change or If I am simply doing something wrong. I haven't found anything related in google searches that solve the issue so I was hoping someone here might be able to help. Here is the code that is producing the error:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

use App\VarName;

class VarController extends Controller {

    public function Var()
    {
        $Variable = VarName::get();

        dd($Variable);
    }
}
```

According to the documentation, this should work, and in the video that I watched, it did work.. what am I missing?

I tried deleting the Controller class, since it seems to be whats causing the already in use error, which broke everything, reinstalled and tried to just use Controller since it extends the eloquent model but now its saying:

ErrorException in Pluralizer.php line 258: `call_user_func()` expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function `mb_strtolower` not found or invalid function name

which is beyond my understanding of the inner workings of Laravel, I'm stuck and I don't understand the problem, according to documentation I don't see anything wrong with my code, this seems like such a simple step. all I'm trying to do is retrieve info from a database, what is going on?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you defined an App\Http\Controllers\Controller class?

Comment: There is a default Controller class, I did not create it but its there.

Comment: does that have something to do with the problem I'm encountering?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;` statement is failing because there is already a `Controller` class in the `App\Http\Controllers` namespace.

To solve the immediate issue, you can change namespace shortcut on the use statement:

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
```

However, the solution for your specific issue is that you probably just want to remove the `use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;` statement altogether.

In Laravel 5, the `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` class already extends the `Illuminate\Routing\Controller` class. The intention is that all new controllers should then extend the `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` class. For example, take a look at the default `App\Http\Controllers\HomeController` or `App\Http\Controllers\WelcomeController`, as both extend the `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` class.

In summary, your two options are:

```
// rename the class in the use statement
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

// note the name of the class being extended
class VarController extends BaseController {
    // snip
}
```

Or

```
// extend the existing App\Http\Controllers\Controller class
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class VarController extends Controller {
    // snip
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I kinda just gave up on trying Laravel 5 due to this, decided to wait till it was a stable release and had specific documentation regarding its differences from 4. have been using 4 without issue and I think I will still wait till 5 is stable, but good to know for future reference!

Comment: It seems to be a bug in the `:generate` in laravel 5

Answer (score 1):

This is because of a duplicate that exists
[image]

Solution is to remove the duplicate from your import
[image]

See attached sample