# Laravel Controller request already in use

Tags: laravel, controller

In my social media i want that can share posts for specific course so i have to make controller more than one. But this is my controller code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request as IRequest;

class TwooneoneController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

but when i write on terminal `route:list`, i am getting this error:

> "Cannot use App\Http\Request as Request because the name is already in use"

Can u please help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as Controller because the name is already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27319560/cannot-use-illuminate-routing-controller-as-controller-because-the-name-is-alrea)

Comment: Why do you assume it is this PHP file the error is coming from?

Comment: Sir, this is my graduation project i work on laravel for 2 months, I am not expert on php. Can u explain me more clear.

Comment: what made you determine that this file you pasted above is the one that is causing your error?  as that error has nothing to do with anything in that file you have above

Comment: Actullay you asked a good point. But the website was working perfectly till i codod this page.

Comment: check if the log has the error message `storage/logs/laravel.log`